# Find / replace colors in (i.e. recolor) a picture

Tags: c#, vb.net, image, powerpoint, gdi+

I am trying to recreate the Recolor Picture dialog that Microsoft unfortunately discontinued in the transition from Office 2003 to 2007.  This was very useful for replacing colors in a picture (see http://www.indezine.com/products/powerpoint/learn/picturesandvisuals/recolor-pictures-ppt2003.html for full description of dialog).

[image]

I am mostly interested in doing this for images in the *metafile* format (EMF or WMF), which tend to have fewer colors than other picture formats, in my experience.  The picture below is an example of an enhanced metafile picture pasted from Excel into PowerPoint that appears to contain just 6 colors:

[image]

If I was able to use the legacy Office dialog pictured above, I would see my 6 colors on the left in the "Original" column, and I could easily change the blue font (and border) color to black. The problem here is that if I use `GetPixel()` to programmatically inventory the colors in the image, I get dozens of colors due to anti-aliasing of the fonts, and it isn't practical to show the user all these recoloring options (which would effectively require the user to manually recreate the proper anti-aliasing effect).  The snippet of code below illustrates how I have tried to inventory the colors:

```
Dim listColors as New List(Of Color)
Dim shp as PowerPoint.Shape = [a metafile picture in PowerPoint]
Dim strTemp as String = Path.Combine(Environ("temp"), "temp_img.emf")
shp.Export(strTemp, PowerPoint.PpShapeFormat.ppShapeFormatEMF, 0, 0)
Using bmp As New Bitmap(strTemp)
    For x As Integer = 0 To bmp.Width - 1
        For y As Integer = 0 To bmp.Height - 1
            listColors.Add(bmp.GetPixel(x, y))
        Next
    Next
End Using
```

I see that there is an optional [Palette property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.palette(v=vs.110).aspx) for metafiles, which I thought could provide an answer, but an exception is thrown when I try to access it, so that was a dead end.  I also see that there are [headers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ay1sftw1(v=vs.110).aspx) for metafile images, but I cannot decipher what to do with them from the limited documentation on the Internet, and I am not even sure that that would get me to the right answer (i.e. 6 colors).

To summarize, part 1 of the question is how to inventory (i.e. identify) the 6 "core" colors in the image above, and part 2 is how to replace one of these 6 colors with another.  VB.NET solutions are preferred, although I can probably translate C# code if not too complex.

If needed, you can download the EMF version of the image above at https://www.dropbox.com/s/n03ys3dh9pcd0xu/temp_img.emf?dl=0.

**EDIT:**  To be clear, I am not interested in "computing" the six "core" colors in the image above.  I believe, perhaps incorrectly, that these six colors are explicit properties of the image, and my first objective is to figure out how to access them.  Indeed, if you simply ungroup the metafile picture twice in PowerPoint, you can loop through the resulting shapes to get these six colors.  That would address part 1 of the question, although it seems a bit sloppy, works only for metafiles (which may be fine, actually), and I doubt that is how the legacy Recolor Picture dialog worked.  To address part 2, I could regroup the metafile picture shapes after swapping colors but, again, that seems sloppy and modifies the picture in ways other than what is intended.  So, how can I explicitly retrieve / modify / set these "core" colors in a [metafile] picture?

Comment: I think the problem is the anti-aliased fonts, you'll either have to alter the image before getting the pixels, get them all or Select all similar colours into a dictionary with the main colour as the key then when that colour is changed, change the others

Comment: If you use a screen looking glass and closely look at screen fonts you see a mulit-colored halo around them, even if they are black..

Comment: @TaW I believe that is what the OPs problem is, or at least part of it

Comment: Indeed, that's why I upvoted your comment; I also agree with your suggestion, how to fix it, although for excel imports one could also have a look at which colors one can actually expect to get from there.. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

So I've had a quick stab at implementing one of my ideas to use a dictionary of colours and what not. The code isn't working properly just yet but I figured I show it here so that you can have a quick look into how it works and develop on it from there.

```
using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(@"InputPath"))
{
    Dictionary<Color, List<Color>> colourDictionary = new Dictionary<Color, List<Color>>();
    int nTolerance = 60;

    int nBytesPerPixel = Bitmap.GetPixelFormatSize(bitmap.PixelFormat) / 8;
    System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData bitmapData = bitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, bitmap.PixelFormat);
    try
    {
        int nByteCount = bitmapData.Stride * bitmap.Height;
        byte[] _baPixels = new byte[nByteCount];

        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(bitmapData.Scan0, _baPixels, 0, _baPixels.Length);
        int _nStride = bitmapData.Stride;

        for (int h = 0; h < bitmap.Height; h++)
        {
            int nCurrentLine = h * _nStride;
            for (int w = 0; w < (bitmap.Width * nBytesPerPixel); w += nBytesPerPixel)
            {
                int nBlue = _baPixels[nCurrentLine + w];
                int nGreen = _baPixels[nCurrentLine + w + 1];
                int nRed = _baPixels[nCurrentLine + w + 2];

                if (colourDictionary.Keys.Count > 0)
                {
                    Color[] caNearbyColours = colourDictionary.Keys.Select(c => c)
                        .Where(c => (int)c.B <= (nBlue + nTolerance) && (int)c.B >= (nBlue - nTolerance)
                            && (int)c.G <= (nGreen + nTolerance) && (int)c.G >= (nGreen - nTolerance)
                            && (int)c.R <= (nRed + nTolerance) && (int)c.R >= (nRed - nTolerance)).ToArray();

                    if (caNearbyColours.Length > 0)
                    {
                        if (!colourDictionary[caNearbyColours.FirstOrDefault()].Any(c => c.R == nRed && c.G == nGreen && c.B == nBlue))
                            colourDictionary[caNearbyColours.FirstOrDefault()].Add(Color.FromArgb(255, nRed, nGreen, nBlue));
                    }
                    else
                        colourDictionary.Add(Color.FromArgb(255, nRed, nGreen, nBlue), new List<Color>());
                }
                else
                    colourDictionary.Add(Color.FromArgb(255, nRed, nGreen, nBlue), new List<Color>());
            }
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        bitmap.UnlockBits(bitmapData);
    }

    using (Bitmap colourBitmap = new Bitmap(bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height, bitmap.PixelFormat))
    {
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(colourBitmap))
        {
            for (int h = 0; h < colourBitmap.Height; h++)
            {
                for (int w = 0; w < colourBitmap.Width; w++)
                {
                    Color colour = bitmap.GetPixel(w, h);
                    if (!colourDictionary.ContainsKey(colour))
                    {
                        Color keyColour = colourDictionary.Keys.FirstOrDefault(k => colourDictionary[k].Any(v => v == colour));

                        colourBitmap.SetPixel(w, h, keyColour);
                    }
                    else
                        colourBitmap.SetPixel(w, h, colour);
                }
            }
        }

        colourBitmap.Save(@"OutputPath", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
    }
}
```

Notice how the top section uses `Lockbits` for better performance. This can easily be transferred onto the bottom section. Also note that the lock bits code is set to work for images with a bytes per pixel of 3 or 4.

Now onto how the code is attempting to work:

It starts off by looping over the initial image and finding colours. If the colour is found already it skips it, however if the colour is not in the dictionary it will add it and also if the colour has a similar colour in the dictionaries keys (will need changing to look at values too) it will add it to it's values.

This then loops through the pixels in the output image setting them according to the keys in the dictionary, thus creating a 'blocked' image.

Now as I said it isn't working just yet, so here are some improvements needed to be made:

- As said above checking the colour to those in the values
- Adding lock bits to the bottom code for better performance
- Tweaking the `nTolerance` value for better results
- Keep track of counts of colours and at the end of looping set the key to that with the largest count
- And of course anything else that I have not thought of

Comment: @MacG Hope this helps to get you started in your problem

Comment: Thanks.  I am aware of LockBits as a faster alternative to GetPixel() to get colors.  However, LockBits will still return all the colors in the image, including those used for anti-aliasing, right?  To get around that, I understand you are using a tolerance to "bucket" colors into fewer buckets, but that seems unreliable for consistently getting the right "core" colors (6, in this example).  Moreover, even if the tolerance concept could properly inventory the 6 colors in part 1, it would create other problems when replacing colors in part 2, such as low-quality or no anti-aliasing, I think.

Comment: @MacG Of course with this approach you're going to lose quality and the anti-aliasing effect. It was an idea that I thought could help you kick start you're thinking. But the way to try and minimise false positives of the tolerance bucket is to make the main colour the one that appears most. You might be able to keep the anti-aliasing effect by instead of using SetPixel by using Graphics and setting the smoothing quality.